# What heroes have voice lines when destroying arcade machines?

Tags: overwatch

In Hanamura, the attackers spawn inside a room full of arcade machines, which everyone proceeds to blow up. I have noticed that when playing as D.Va, she will say, "No one can beat my high scores" when destroying them. Are there any other heroes besides D.Va that have voice lines when destroying the arcade machines?

Comment: They're *arcade* machines. Arqade is this website, arcade is a place with games things/class of games machine.

Comment: Are you sure those lines are triggered by D.Va destroying the machine, and not just her initial spawn in? Several characters make reference to the arcade machines at some point during the pre-game

Comment: @Unionhawk it was an intentional spelling.

Comment: @twobugs I've only heard it while she is destroying the machines. And I have played her on defense and she hasn't made the quote, so I believe it is from destroying them, though I could be wrong.

Comment: At least Genji also has an attack specific line for Hanamura that can play and irregular times. I don't think this necessarily means D.Va is responding to destroying the arcade machines.

Answer (score 1):

[The quote](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/D.Va/Quotes#Map-Specific) is map specific but doesn't require you to break any arcades.

I'm saying this from both personnal experience and the fact that the source doesn't mention the specificity of destroying arcade booths.

So no heroes have voice line **whilest destroying arcade machines**.